# How to create a navigation main menu in SDL Tridion 8.5?

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

I have tried to create a navigation menu in SDL Tridion 8.5 but it's not working. The menu is not hyperlinked since the code is wrong. I have given the code below. Kindly help me since I am new to SDL Tridion

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li ID="tcm:1-2-4" Title="010_Home" class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li ID="tcm:1-2-5" Title="020_Examples"><a href="examples.html">Examples</a></li>
          <li ID="tcm:1-2-6" Title="010_Contact Us"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: welcome to tridion stackexchange , can you please provide more details on what templating are you using to generate the navigation.

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver templating

Answer (score 3):

Based on your answer it looks like you are trying to create header navigation using DWTs. For this you need to create appropriate schemas (with embedded fields) and then read them using DWTs. Once you add default finish action over your Template, links should be resolved. However, we are unsure what is your level of knowledge in Tridion, but Stack Exchange and docs.sdl.com will be your best friends in future. :D

For example, [this blog](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/01/combined-layout-template-building-block.html) can help you take initial insight at how DWT templating works.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to tridion world.

to answer your question you can create a Template building block using c# and include that template building block within a template. e.g navigation template or sitemap.

Purpose of this template will be as follows:

1. it will create a XML by scanning through all structure groups and pages and metadata.
2. Next you can apply proper styling using that xml to render navigation.

if sitemap xml page is already created for your website. you can reuse it.

You will find many blog posts on c# template building block or creation of sitemap xml using c# etc.

All the best.